# I have to make a function returns a list that has all the inputs that the user put as numbers ,and in the last element is the sum of all the elements,

Tags: python

```
def input_list():
    my_list = []
    while True:
        num = (input(''))
        if num == '':
             break
        my_list.append(float(num))
        my_list.append(sum(my_list))
```

E.g. if I put number 5 and 2 as the user I'm getting a list [5.0,5.0,2.0,12.0], can someone tell me why?

Comment: The issue is that you calculate and insert the sum in each loop iteration rather than just once at the end. Also I recommend learning to use a [debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html), which is really something any developer needs to learn on day 1. It's absolutely trivial to find issues like this with a debugger and you'd be doing yourself a huge disservice by not learning how to use one. It'd be like trying to learn carpentry while not being able to see or touch anything.

Comment: thank you a lot, haven't even noticed, thanks for the advice too:)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the last line indented, which is causing you to append the sum with each new input. If you move the last line out of your while loop as shown below, you should get [5.0, 2.0, 7.0]

```
def input_list():
    my_list = []
    while True:
        num = (input(''))
        if num == '':
             break
        my_list.append(float(num))
    my_list.append(sum(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You calculate and insert the sum in each loop iteration rather than just once at the end.

```py
def input_list():
    my_list = []
    while True:
        num = (input(''))
        if num == '':
             break
        my_list.append(float(num))
    my_list.append(sum(my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are mostly right. you have your sum inside of your loop so on every number you add to you are then adding the sum of what currently is there. move the my_list.append(sum(my_list)) outside and it will work

```
def input_list(): 
   my_list = [] 
   while True: 
       num = (input('')) 
       if num == '': 
           break 
       my_list.append(float(num)) 
   my_list.append(sum(my_list))
   return my_list
```